# Enabling Pilot Feature

Tags: pilot

I like to enable some pilot features of salesforce in my dev org. Unfortunately i'm not able to open a case since it is a dev org. please help me with alternate solutiion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you register as a Salesforce partner, you will have access to the partner portal where you can log a case to request access to a pilot feature. You could also try engaging with the feature's product manager on Success Community, or the Partner Community.